# Python - Webscraping: Fails to get single item from dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

I have a script that adds (scrapes) links to a dictionary, then scrapes for each of theses links individually:

It gives me the error: requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['link1, link2, link3 ']", whereby instead of link1 the urls are printed, i just dont write them here for readability. Why does my script fail to use each dict item individually and tries to connect to the whole dict instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is in the line
`links.append(result)`

You want

`links.extend(result)`